# HTML5: What should server do when user uploads folder?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

HTML5 does not allow directory upload.

But inevitably, some users will end up uploading a folder, because they don't know about HTML5 rules.
The uploaded folder is just a small file.

How should I handle those cases?

- Should I pretend the user really wanted to upload this small (probably meaningless) file?
- Should I try to check if uploaded file is actually a folder, and warn the user if it is? (the actual data of a folder file is different on every OS, so not that easy)
- Is it the browser's fault, should Chrome prevent the user from HTML5-uploading a folder?

Note: [Alfresco](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-12973) uses the first strategy. If you know any application that uses the second strategy I would be glad to hear about it.

Comment: Different but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590058/does-html5-allow-drag-drop-upload-of-folders-or-a-folder-tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alfresco has recently changed their strategy to the second strategy.

If the uploaded item is a folder or has a null size, it is refused server-side, and the Web UI tells the user.

I guess it is the best thing to do for now.