# jQuery-File-Upload plugin - can't drop folder

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I'm trying to implement [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) - I have it working when I drag & drop files from explorer into my browser. But I also want to be able to drag and drop a folder.

When I drop files onto the browser, the files are in the data.files param in the fileuploaddrop(e, data) event handler. But when I drop a folder, the files array is empty.

```
var dropZone = $('#fileUploadDiv').fileupload({
    dropZone : $('.dropZone'),
    drop : function(e, data) {
      $.each(data.files, function(index, file) {
        console.log('Dropped file: ' + file.name);
      });
    }
}).
```

Is this not supported by the plugin, or is there a mystery setting I'm missing somewhere ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The uploader uses HTML5 capabilities, which don't allow dropping folders. Read more here: [Does HTML5 allow drag-drop upload of folders or a folder tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590058/does-html5-allow-drag-drop-upload-of-folders-or-a-folder-tree)

Answer (score 2):

Drag/Drop and input Directory upload now available with chrome 21

you can get directory upload using webkitdirectory

```
<input type='file' webkitdirectory>
```

Here is a complete code for uploading folders.

https://protonet.info/en/blog/html5-experiment-drag-drop-of-folders/

Comment: This seems to limit to only directories. Is there any way to select both files and directories?