# Is there a way to read contents of a directory from web app

Tags: java, web-applications, file-io

I have a web application built on the JVM. In this application the users are able to upload files. I read the contents of the file and do "something" with it.

In addition to this, I would like to give option to the users to put in a directory path. This directory path will be read by the application and the directory will be scanned for all relevant files (.CSV). And each will be processed.

**Questions**

- Will the web-application be able to scan the directory located on the users machine? Or the directory path need to be in a network to which the web-app has access to?
- I will be using the Commons IO package to scan the directory for files and process the files, is there a better approach?

Comment: please note that to do this, there will be all sorts of permissions issues you will encounter.  You will need to sign the app, and by its nature, your app will be suspicious.

Comment: Thats what I thought. In that case I would not want to scan the directory located on the users computer, however, a directory located on the network to which the user and my app have access to. Is that doable?

Comment: well "a network" is still a client filesystem.  If it is YOUR network, then you can pre-configure things however you want and there won't be a problem.  In that case, however, you still have the problem where the user has a file that your network does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access file system of user machine from pure web application. This task can be implemented using trusted applet or java application executed via java web start or trusted flash component or other native component (browser plugin).

Applets are almost obsolete and require JVM on client side. Java web start still requires JVM. All signed components (java based, flash, native code) require user approval.

I think that better and more modern way is to use a great feature of HTML 5 that allows not navigation to specific location on disk (that was possible since HTML 1.0) but also selecting a full directory.

Take a look on the following discussion for details: [Does HTML5 allow drag-drop upload of folders or a folder tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590058/does-html5-allow-drag-drop-upload-of-folders-or-a-folder-tree)

Comment: Maybe today this API can be useful [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API)