# Maximum files of a directory that can be read by FileReader#readEntries in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, fileapi

I'm creating a Chrome application. I must read the files of a directory and I am using the [DirectoryEntry API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DirectoryEntry) and [DirectoryReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DirectoryReader).

My problem is that the maximum files read using DirectoryReader#readEntries is 100, the first 100 (alphabetical order)

```
var reader = currentDir.createReader();
var read = reader.readEntries.bind(reader, function(files) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
         if (files[i].name == nameSearches){
                callback(files[i]);
            }

        }
    })
    callback(undefined)
}
read();
```

The value of `files.length` is `100` and there are more files in the directory

I'm not sure if this limitation is about Google Chrome, Google Chrome Applications, Javascript... and if this limitation can be overcomed

With the solution marked the result code is this:

```
var reader = currentDir.createReader();
var read = reader.readEntries.bind(reader, function(files) {
    if (files.lenght == 0) {
        callback(undefined);
    }
    for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        if (files[i].name == nameSearches){
                callback(files[i]);
            }

        }
    })
    read();

}
read();
```

Comment: You may also have a look on [bro-fs](https://github.com/vitalets/bro-fs) package that solves this issue and also provides handy promise-based interface to files API.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Read the docs you linked!

> The only method for this interface, `readEntries()` is for listing all
>   the files and folders in a directory. To list all the entries, you
>   need to do the following:
>
> 1. Call `directoryEntry.createReader()` to create a new `DirectoryReader`.
> 2. Call `readEntries()`.
> 3. **Continue calling `readEntries()` until an empty
>      array is returned.** You have to do this because the API might not
>      return all entries in a single call.

Comment: A lot of thanks. I was just thinking about that solution after writing the post. And obviously works. And the example explains it (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DirectoryReader). I must improve search for solutions...

Comment: WTF the readEntries() reads just a part of the entries. Bad design, the function should explicitly accept a parameter of maximum number of entries returned per call (with NO default value). How do you "continue calling the function" if the function is asyncronous?

Comment: Gianluca Ghettini : You create a recursive function that calls readEntries again if the result of read entries isn't an empty array. So if you have 325 items, it will be called five times, returning 100, 100, 100, 25 then 0 items. Once it returns zero, you don't call it again.

Comment: Oh boy this sucks bigtime, because it looks like it is working and only when you try it with a lot of files it's incomplete. I'm with Gianluca here, there should be a required parameter of some kind to acknowledge this behaviour.