# I have to upload a folder( all the contents of a folder it contains different types of files ) through a web form in Spring boot web app

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, file-upload

I have to upload a folder( all the contents of a folder it contains different types of files and nested folder also, I just want to upload the files) through a web form in Spring boot web app.
I have to make manipulations on the file and save and return them. 
I am facing problem with the upload part of the folder.
Can anyone suggest me something, how to upload whole folder through a web form in SpringBoot.

Comment: If you want to upload the whole folder then you can create a zip file which acts like a single file, there can be other ways also

Comment: For the same https://www.baeldung.com/java-compress-and-uncompress this might help you if you want to go with it

Comment: @PatelRomil, Thanks for your answer. Can there be any alternate solution for the same, because after manipulation I have to store it locally in my workspace and return as well. Zip file might create a problem in that

Comment: I don't think so zip will create any problem. which kind of problem you are talking about. meanwhile, I have found these two articles which might help of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885971/how-to-implement-folder-upload-in-a-spring-web-app https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/651684/how-to-upload-a-folder-using-java

Comment: @PatelRomil Thanks a lot for your assistance. I'll implement this and get in touch with you regarding the same. Thanks