# Is it possible to upload solid folder in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I researched a lot to find out how can we upload solid folder in codeigniter but the only solution i got is, uploading multiple files but not solid folder? Can anyone help me out...

Thanks for million.

Comment: Your question doesn't have much to do with CodeIgniter. Start by trying to find out if and how you can upload a folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does HTML5 allow drag-drop upload of folders or a folder tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590058/does-html5-allow-drag-drop-upload-of-folders-or-a-folder-tree)

Answer (score 1):

We can't upload solid folders in codeigniter unless you compressed it as .rar or .zip or something like that..