# Handle directory/files upload with one input javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-filesystem

I want to allow users dragging and uploading directory and files.

i know i could create

```
<input type="file" multiple />
<!-- for files/multiple files upload-->
```

and

```
<input type="file" directory mozDirectory webkitDirectory />
<!-- for directory uploads -->
```

i tried detecting while user is dragging the item if it is a directory or file and setting directory attribute depending on that, but turns out that javascript doesn't allow you to check that.

also i have seen on lot of websites that users are able to drag both files and directories together and even multiple directories.

how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dragging and droppping of folders is available in `Chrome >= 21`

Here's what you need (Not tried, but it can give you the idea):

```
function traverseFileTree(item, path) {
  path = path || "";
  if (item.isFile) {
    // Get file
    item.file(function(file) {
      console.log("File:", path + file.name);
    });
  } else if (item.isDirectory) {
    // Get folder contents
    var dirReader = item.createReader();
    dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
      for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
        traverseFileTree(entries[i], path + item.name + "/");
      }
    });
  }
}

dropArea.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var items = event.dataTransfer.items;
  for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    // webkitGetAsEntry is where the magic happens
    var item = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
    if (item) {
      traverseFileTree(item);
    }
  }
}, false);
```

More information can be found [here](https://protonet.info/en/blog/html5-experiment-drag-drop-of-folders/)

Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11410455/3514160)

Comment: thanks for the tree function, it'll be usefull but how can i know if user dragged folder or item in the input?

Comment: I use it with TypeScript and in Firefox, and it works.

Comment: @JohannesFlügel Glad to hear that.. :) Happy Coding.. Cheers.