# HTML File Input - How do I allow files and directories?

Tags: javascript, html, file, webkit

I currently have the following:

```
<input id="file-upload-input" type="file" multiple="" webkitdirectory="webkitDirectory">
```

This works great for uploading directories, but I can no longer select individual files.  Is there no way to support uploading files and directories?

Comment: It must be included to support uploading folders.  I want to support folder or file, not one or the other.

Comment: In that case, it looks like you'll have to use JS. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049276/handle-directory-files-upload-with-one-input-javascript

Comment: @ochi, unfortunately, that only deals with drag-and-drop. My drag-and-drop functionality works exactly as it should, but the modal file input popup is what I'm trying to solve right now.

Answer (score 1):

As for today, You cant do with html only.
You will have to use JS code or adding 2 input 1 per each type (file & folder)