# How to you pass a directory's structure to ng-file-upload directive in Chrome Browser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, file-upload

Using the following Angular JS directive: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Wondering if there's a simplified way to pass in the relative path to a file object. 
I have checked the following issue:  https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/285

From it, I discovered that I can create a field file._relativePath, but it seems like this variable does not work by itself and I would have to receive it from chrome  [like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590058/does-html5-allow-drag-drop-upload-of-folders-or-a-folder-tree?)

This is less an issue with the project than a question of my experience but I'm wondering how would you be able to combine the two together to get the path for each file in relativePath? Any example or link that explains things beyond 285 to make this easier would really be appreciated.

Apologies if the question is not strong enough or is very similar to another one that's answered. New to asking on Stack Overflow. Constructive feedback is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file.path should be used to retrieve the relative path instead of file.relativePath.  [Check this link for more information.](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/846)