# How to select a folder from my computer and store the path of the folder in a textbox in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have tried FileUpload, it can select only files and also I cannot get full path of the file when I try with browsers other than Internet Explorer. I think I need an alternative for FolderBrowserDialog for asp.net.

Comment: You can't get the full-path of the client-file, only the filename. Why do you need it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does HTML5 allow drag-drop upload of folders or a folder tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590058/does-html5-allow-drag-drop-upload-of-folders-or-a-folder-tree)

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the full filepath from a file being upload, because it's on the client's computer, the browser has no access to this information, for security.