# Best react drag and drop component with support to select file

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-redux

I want a drag and drop component that will support single file drop, multi file drop and dir drop. If you drop a directory then all the child files should be expanded in the droppable area and should be collapsible.. Also I should be able to remove the files. Any existing react component that can meet my requirement or close to this.

I want a look and feel like this-

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. :-)

Comment: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/
https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd

Comment: I used this component just for DnD https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone and worked pretty well

Comment: @Polak https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone don't support dir drag and drop. right ?

Comment: No, when you drop something into the component you will get an object, it doesn't do any extra job, once you get the object will be able to check for isFile or isDirectory property, for directories, you'll have to implement a way to navigate and get the files.
This link could help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590058/does-html5-allow-drag-drop-upload-of-folders-or-a-folder-tree