# File and Directory Entries API broken in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

I'm trying to use the File and Directory Entries API to create a file uploader tool that will allow me to drop an arbitrary combination of files and directories into a browser window, to be read and uploaded.

(I'm fully aware that similar functionality can be achieved by using an file input element with `webkitdirectory` enabled, but I'm testing a use case where the user isn't forced to put everything into a single folder)

Using the Drag and Drop API, I've managed to read the `DataTransfer` items and convert them to `FileSystemEntry` objects using `DataTransferItem.webkitGetAsEntry`.

From there, I am able to tell that if the entry is a `FileSystemFileEntry` or a `FileSystemDirectoryEntry`. My plan of course if to recursively walk the directory structure, if any, which I should be able to do using the `FileSystemDirectoryReader` method `readEntries`, like this:

```
handleDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    //assuming I dropped only one directory
    const directory = event.dataTransfer.items[0];
    const directoryEntry = directory.webkitGetAsEntry();
    const directoryReader = directoryEntry.createReader();
    directoryReader.readEntries(function(entires){
        // callback: the "entries" param is an Array 
        // containing the directory entries
    });
}
```

However, I'm running into the following issue: in Chrome, the readEntries method **only returns 100 entries**. Apparently, this is the expected behavior as the way to obtain subsequent files from the directory is to call `readEntries` again. However, I'm finding this impossible to do. A subsequent call to the method throws the error:

`DOMException: An operation that depends on state cached in an interface object was made but the state had changed since it was read from disk.`

Does anyone know a way around this? Is this API hopelessly broken for directories of 100+ files in Chrome? Is this API deprecated? (not that it was ever "precated"). In Firefox, `readEntries` returns the whole directory content at once, which apparently against the spec, but it is usable.

Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, as soon as I had posted this question the answer hit me. What I was trying to do was akin to the following:

```
handleDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    //assuming I dropped only one directory
    const directory = event.dataTransfer.items[0];
    const directoryEntry = directory.webkitGetAsEntry();
    const directoryReader = directoryEntry.createReader();
    directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries){
        // callback: the "entries" param is an Array 
        // containing the directory entries
    }, );
    directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries){
        //call entries a second time
    });
}
```

The problem with this is that readEntries is asynchronous, so I'm trying to call it while it's "busy" reading the first batch (I'm sure lower-level programmers will have a better term for that). A better way of achieving what I was trying to do:

```
handleDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    //assuming I dropped only one directory
    const directory = event.dataTransfer.items[0];
    const directoryEntry = directory.webkitGetAsEntry();
    const directoryReader = directoryEntry.createReader();

    function read(){
        directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries){
            if(entries.length > 0) {
                //do something with the entries
                read(); //read the next batch
            } else {
                //do whatever needs to be done after
                //all files are read
            }
        });
    }
    read();
}
```

This way we ensure the `FileSystemDirectoryReader` is done with one batch before starting the next one.

Comment: Interesting usage issue you caught there; would have hoped the docs would have noted this but it is a 'non-standard' feature. Could also do this with `await`/`async` similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53058574/885922