# how to upload directories to golang server from html?

Tags: go, directory, upload

I found many tutorials about uploading files from html input file type to golang server. But I can't find a proper way of how folders are uploaded to golang server and how golang server handle those folders.
Is there any tutorial or reference i can follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML does allow you to select folders to upload but it's not the way you want. You can make some changes to achieve what you need.

First, take a look at this answer on how to handle folder selects on HTML input:
[Does HTML5 allow drag-drop upload of folders or a folder tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590058)

Now if you want the folders too and not just the files, you can send the data in a way that you know which folder they belong and you can create the folders on your golang server or handle them any other way you might want. But if you just need the files, then that answer should be good enough for you.